# Unit Test failing when comparing two objects in VS 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, object

I have the following unit test:

```
  Public Sub pickWeaponTest_Rock()
        Dim lastMove As String = "Rock"
        Dim actualSelectedMove As Weapon = New Paper()

        Dim result As Weapon

        Dim target As Object = New PlayerComputerTactical() ' TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        result = target.pickWeapon()
        Assert.AreEqual(result, actualSelectedMove)
        Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot be verified.")
    End Sub
```

I get the following error, even though both are Paper objects:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:. Actual:.

Could someone please shed some light as to how to get this working.

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing two **different** `Paper` objects.
You need to override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` to consider them equal.

However, if you want all instances of the class to be equal, you should use an enum instead.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I'm new to programming to apologies for my lack of knowledge. I tried   Assert.Equals(result.GetHashCode(), actualSelectedMove.GetHashCode()) is that correct?

Comment: @AtiqJaved: No; not at all.  You need to **override** the `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` methods in the class to tell .Net when two instances are equal.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx

Comment: It sounds like you should use an enum instead.

Comment: Could you please provide example as to how I would code this?